# How do I generate a URL for children of a WCM Site Area?

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I have a servlet that uses the WCM 8.5 API to fetch the children of a SiteArea or and prints the contents in an unordered list. My question is how can I generate a URL to each piece of content so that my list can link out to the content or child portal pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a menu component.

Use location as a search criteria. 
In the result design add the element tag pointing to autofill site area. 
It will look somewhat like this:

Header:

```
<ul>
```

Result Design:

```
<li>[Element context="autofill" type="content" key="Whichever_Key_used"]  </li>
```

Footer:

```
 </ul>
```

And you can point your servlet to fetch this menu component.